# Perl JSON to treat all numbers as string

Tags: json, perl

In order to create an API that's consistent for strict typing languages, I need to modify all JSON to return quoted strings in place of integers without going through one-by-one and modifying underlying data.

This is how JSON is generated now:

```
  my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref->allow_unknown->allow_blessed->utf8;
  $output = $json->encode($hash);
```

What would be a good way to say, "And quote every scalar within that $hash"?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm#simple_scalars

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both of JSON's backends (JSON::PP and JSON::XS) base the output type on the internal storage of the value. The solution is to stringify the non-reference scalars in your data structure.

```
sub recursive_inplace_stringification {
   my $reftype = ref($_[0]);
   if (!length($reftype)) {
      $_[0] = "$_[0]" if defined($_[0]);
   }
   elsif ($reftype eq 'ARRAY') {
      recursive_inplace_stringification($_) for @{ $_[0] };
   }
   elsif ($reftype eq 'HASH') {
      recursive_inplace_stringification($_) for values %{ $_[0] };
   }
   else {
      die("Unsupported reference to $reftype\n");
   }
}

# Convert numbers to strings.
recursive_inplace_stringification($hash);

# Convert to JSON.
my $json = JSON->new->allow_nonref->utf8->encode($hash);
```

If you actually need the functionality provided by `allow_unknown` and `allow_blessed`, you will need to reimplement it inside of `recursive_inplace_stringification` (perhaps by copying it from JSON::PP if licensing allows), or you could use the following before calling `recursive_inplace_stringification`:

```
# Convert objects to strings.
$hash = JSON->new->allow_nonref->decode(
   JSON->new->allow_nonref->allow_unknown->allow_blessed->encode(
      $hash));
```

Comment: `$_[0] = "$_[0]"` does nothing to the value of non-referential scalars

Comment: It depends on what referential scalar is. `perl -E 'sub{ $_[0] .= "idesh" }->($x=3); say $x'`

Comment: @Borodin, Perl passes arguments by reference, so that replaces the argument with its stringification. Since the value is now stored as a string, JSON will output it as a string. `perl -MJSON -E'$x = 4; say encode_json([$x]); sub { $_[0] = "$_[0]" }->($x); say encode_json([$x]);'`

Comment: [An earlier answer on how Perl passes by reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316425/perl-hash-pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference/15318237#15318237)